# how do I get cursor:pointer on an embedded object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

1) I am trying to place a transparent image over an embedded object. I am missing positions, relative and absolute, somewhere. But where?

I am actually placing the transparent image because I cannot use `cursor:pointer` for the object embed. So my idea was to place a transparent image and use `cursor:pointer`.

2) Why doesn't `onclick` work in IE? It works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<div id="divmarquee" runat="server" >
     <img id="imgtrans" runat="server" src= "/images/480x75-blank-transparent" title="Click Here" style="position:relative" />
           <object width="475px" height="75px" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'; return false;">
                 <embed src="merchant_images/The_Marquee_Dealn.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="z-index: 0; cursor:pointer" wmode="transparent" width="475px" height="75px"> 
                 </embed>
            </object> 
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A more poignant question would be "how do I get cursor:pointer on an embedded object"

Answer (score 1):

With your given code, add the position values to `position: relative` on `#divmarquee`, and change position to `position: absolute` and add `cursor: pointer` on `#imgtrans`:

```
#divmarquee { position: relative; }
#imgtrans { position: absolute; cursor: pointer; }
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/pJZ2t/

Answer (score 0):

In your code above you added cursor: pointer to the embed-tag. Try moving it to the image tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the cursor: pointer style to divmarquee.

Answer (score 0):

For your onclick problem try these:

first, try

```
onclick = function(){window.location='http://www.google.com';return false;}
```

then try to change it to this:

```
onclick = window.location.href='somesite'
```

you can also try:

```
onclick = document.location='somesite'
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
var el = document.getElementById("imgtrans").firstChild;
if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener(
      'click', 
      function(){
               window.location='http://www.google.com';
               return false;},
      false); //Decent Browsers
       } 
else if (el.attachEvent){
      el.attachEvent(
          'onclick',
          function(){
               window.location='http://www.google.com';
               return false;
          }
      ); 
}//IE
```

ONE OF THOSE WILL WORK

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divmarquee" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; position:relative; cursor:pointer">   
 <div style="z-index: 0; position:relative">
<object width="475px" height="75px" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'; return false;">
<embed src="merchant_images/The_Marquee_Dealn.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="475px" height="75px">
</embed>
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`cursor: pointer` will work when you wrap the object in a html hyperlink.

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't work. :( Any other way that you know?

Comment: have u tried removing z-index and using <a> tags , coz IE always had issues wid z-index

Comment: This would work provided that you have set an href for the anchor. Would be a good idea to preventDefault/return false from an onclick handler to ensure the link doesn't try to navigate